I am facing an error while connecting my socket server. The server is not connecting
I am trying to create a socket server using node js and express but it returns the following error:
Error in Postman
This is my code:
App is an express server running on 5000
app setup:
const app = express();
const start = async () => {
try {
     await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
     app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
} catch (error) {
     console.error(error);
     process.exit(1);
}
};
start();

module.exports = app;

I have tried using Server from socket and also using socket.io-client. I am new to socket and can't figure out what is wrong as this same code snippet works in a blank project I am setting up but not on the project I am working on

Put all code inside the question, adding links to code does not help.

You will need to instal the socketIO client and configure like the code below for it to work
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// Create a server instance
const server = http.createServer(app);

// Initialize socket.io and pass the server instance
const io = socketIo(server);

// Connect to MongoDB
const start = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        });
        console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

start();

// Define socket.io event handlers
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('A client connected');
    
    // Handle socket events here
    // For example:
    // socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    //     console.log('message: ' + msg);
    //     io.emit('chat message', msg);
    // });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('A client disconnected');
    });
});

// Start listening on the specified port
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});

module.exports = app;

